# Suitable replacement for decodeBuffer Method in Commons Codec

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes, apache-commons

I have a piece of code which encrypts and decrypts using AES algorithm, which was using sun.misc.* packages.

Later i came to know it is wrong to use those set of packages which made me follow the advice of using Apache's  Commons Codec which is effective.

**The previous code was as below :**

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


import sun.misc.*;

public class AESencrp {
private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = 
    new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't','S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
}



}
```

As suggested I have removed sun.misc and did the following alteration.

**After replacing BASE64Encoder class with Base64 in Apache's commons codec:**

```
 public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
            byte[] encryptedValue = new Base64().encode(encVal);
            return new String(encryptedValue);
        }
```

I am not able to find a suitable replacement for decryption as i am struck at line:

```
byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
```

I am not finding any method which does the job of decodeBuffer(String encryptedData) and returns me a byte array of decodedValue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, Then what about this?

Using apache Base64 util class is similar to that of sun.misc.Base64Encoder. Apache Base64 class provides many overload methods that will relieve you of conversion between bytes and String.

```
byte[] encodedBytes  = Base64.encodeBase64(testString.getBytes());

String decodedString = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes));
```

Comment: No, i cannot do like this to decode. The logic for decoding is there 
in public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) , a method mentioned above.

I have encoded string variable by name encryptedData,
Base64.decodeBase64(bytes [] encbytes) takes a byte array.

I am asking a suitable replacement for decodeBuffer(String encString).

which is taking a string parameter and doing some operation of decoding and converting into byte stream.

Comment: Base64.decodeBase64(bytes [] encbytes) takes a byte array. Instead you want it to take string right?

Comment: yes, The above logic for decryption of the method is the one i am forced to follow.

Comment: But are you allowed to use Base64 Commons Codec or not? If yes, Take a string in your method, convert it to byte[] internally and give the byte[] to the decodeBase64 method and get the output in string which you can return from your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EncryptionDecrption {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'e', 'R', 'o', 'o', 'K', 'n', 'a', 't','E','n', 'i', 'r','i','n'};

    public EncryptionDecrption(){

    }

    public static String setEncryptedString(String data) throws Exception {
        Key key = getKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedValue, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public static String getDecryptedValue(String data) throws Exception {

        if(data != null) {
            Key key = getKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decodebyte = Base64.decode(data.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decodebyte);

            return new String(decValue);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Key getKey() throws Exception {
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    }
}
```

it works for me in Android.